# Evaluate $\int\tan^2(x)\sec(x)\ dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

What would be the integration of $\displaystyle\tan^2(x)\sec(x)\ dx$?
I have solved this by using reduction formula as
$\displaystyle(\sec^2(x)-1)\sec(x)=\sec^3(x)-\sec(x)$
and then i apply reduction formula. but i want to know is there any other way to solve this rather than reduction formula??

Comment: please use MathJax. Noone can read this.

Comment: $\tan^2 \sec = \frac{\sin^2}{\cos^3}$ looks like logarithmic integration could be the way to go.

Comment: See also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed#Integration_by_parts

Comment: thanx lab bhattacharjee.. i was helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take advantage of: $\frac{d}{dx}(\cos^{-2}{x}) = -2 \cos^{-3}{x} \, \sin{x}$ and write your integral as follows:

$$I = -\frac{1}{2} \int \sin{x} \, (-2  \, \sin{x} \cos^{-3} {x}) \, dx ,$$

apply now the chain rule to obtain:

$$I = -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}} - \int \frac{\cos{x}}{\cos^2 x} \, dx  \right) = -\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}} - \int \sec{x} \, dx  \right) . $$
Recall now [that](http://symbolab.com/math/search/%5Cint%20sec%5Cleft%28t%5Cright%29dt/?origin=enterkey):

$$\int \sec{x} \, dx = \ln{(\tan{x} + \sec{x})},$$

and substitute back in $I$.

Cheers!

Comment: nice one, but you mean ibp not chain rule don't you?   I'm studying advanced calculus and learning more by looking at these q&a than I am on my course!

Comment: Hi @TooTone. Yes, I meant integration by parts. I often call this chain rule too because they are deeply related. Cheers!